# Can I orient the entrance to my Magnificent Mansion any way I like?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Suppose I want to have my Magnificent Mansion be accessible via a trap door in a ceiling (which one would climb up into) or a cellar entrance (which one would climb down into), rather than the more traditional vertical doorway. Is there anything preventing me from doing so?

The relevant text from the spell is:

> You choose where [the mansion's] one entrance is located. The entrance ... is 5 feet wide and 10 feet tall.

The use of the word "tall" vaguely implies that the entrance must be vertical like a regular old boring door, but that hardly seems conclusive.

I'm mostly asking this for flavor reasons, but I suppose the answer also has some mechanical implications, since one could, for example, create an invisible trap by putting the entrance on the floor of a hallway and then opening it while the quarry walks over it, causing them to fall in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Up to the DM

As you mentioned, technically the only thing limitating it on the RAW is the wording "X ft tall", which only makes sense to a vertical door. Even considering it, the interpretation is vague, so it's **up to the DM**.

## Flavor - OK

As a DM, I don't see any reason to not allow it **for flavor**. You, as a player, are having fun using it that way and it lets your imagination flow. No problem.

## Mechanical? Might not be OK

However, this "creative" use of spells **must be taken care** when used for Mechanical reasons, as allowing a spell to do more than it was written/intended to do is usually dangerous and leads to lower-level spells being more powerful than higher-level ones or spellcasters getting an even larger edge over martial fighters. In this case, the wording of "X ft tall" should be enough of a reason to not allow the use if the DM finds it abusive somehow.

## But this is *my* view on it

So ask **your** DM about it. RAW is vague enough for you to argue for it, although if he decides that he won't allow it, he has enough back up and it shouldn't lead to a further discussion.

Comment: I think this about covers it.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what your GM says. If one of my players came to me with this and could come up with a really good reason why it would be on the floor or just has a narrative reason why it would not be a typical vertical door, then its more or less to me just describing the dimensions of the door. However, I'm not your GM and as such, I feel like this is a question for them.